Make EPPlus chart show data in hidden rows and columns
I am using EPPlus to generante a chart in an Excel file. The chart uses data that is within colasped rows. When I expand the rows the chart shows the data as bars. When the rows are colapsed the chart bars dissappear. This is the standard behaviour of Excel. I want EPPlus to always show the chart data regardless of the rows being colapsed.
The setting in Excel to stop this from happening (to always ensure the chart shows data) is
right click chart -> Select Data -> Hidden and Empty Cells -> tick "Show data in hidden and rows and columns".
Does anyone know the equivalent configuration of the EPPlus chart object or it child propeties to enable the above?
Right click the chart and click "select data"

Click the "Hidden and empty Cells"


The property to set is ShowHiddenData on the Chart object. Example:
ExcelWorksheet sheet; // your worksheet
ExcelScatterChrat chart = sheet.Drawings.AddScatterChart(
   "chart name", 
   eScatterChartType.XYScatterLinesNoMarkers);
chart.ShowHiddenData = true;

